# Declaring val in scala object different to in function

Tags: scala

This code results in `system` being `null:

```
object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("Done")
  } 
}
```

But if I move the declaration of `system` into `main`, it is correctly initialised. Why is that?

Comment: system being `null` when? How do you asses it?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella if I use it in `main()` it's null. If I break on the `println` and inspect it, it's null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation  of `App`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) (emphasis mine):

> ### Caveats
>
> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the `DelayedInit` functionality, which means that **fields of the object will not have been initialized before the main method has been executed**.
>
> It should also be noted that **the `main` method should not be overridden**: the whole class body becomes the “main method”.

Just do

```
object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")  
  println("Done")
}
```

or

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
    println("Done")
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Alternately, remove `extends App` and `override` from the original code.